# How to using the framework called Springboard

Tags: iphone

The framework called Springboard is the iphone kernel.I want to make it supported multitasking.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413154/how-to-implement-daemon-process-for-background-task-in-iphone-sdk-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SpringBoard is a *user-land application* which hosts the "homepage" and many other services (e.g. converting HID events to GSEvents, receiving push notification, alarms, etc.) There aren't any framework nor kernel extensions called SpringBoard.
2. If you want multitasking, just install [backgrounder](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-backgrounder/).