# Is it possible to run a background process on the iPhone using private APIs?

Tags: iphone

I am not planning to send the application to the store, it would be for a limited distribution. I was thinking that if I could use the private API to do background process, I could then I could join the iphone developer enterprise program, and distribute within my company an application which works in the background. I guess an extension of the question would be, if I am an enterprise developer is there a way to achieve background processing without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably against the SDK rules, even for enterprise deployment.

But blocking in `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)app` will probably work.

(there's a clever solution here: [How to implement Daemon process for background task in iphone sdk 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413154/how-to-implement-daemon-process-for-background-task-in-iphone-sdk-3-0/1421519#1421519))