# How to add Daemon services and where i get best tutorial or best practices in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Thanks for helping me answering this question,
  I want to update the user's location and a timer frequently in my application in background. I have heard that the iPhone SDK only provides support for push notification services. Is there a way using the iPhone SDK to add Daemon services? Where can I find a good tutorial?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413154/how-to-implement-daemon-process-for-background-task-in-iphone-sdk-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background processes aren't available on the iPhone when using the official SDK.

The only way to do this is to jailbreak and use undocumented/private APIs, which is not recommended and will prevent your app from being allowed on the App Store.

However, if you just want to update the users location while the app is running, you can do that using NSTimer. It's unclear in your question whether you want the functionality to run while the app is not being used - in which case, my first statement stands.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do it without the app running. Then it's not possible.