# How to write a background service in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I want to write a background service in iphone which will send and receive UDP messages from a live server. after having search on google I am not able to write code from background service.
?

like as we can `extends Service` in Android ..

I could not find any link which could help me in writing code for service.

any tutorial or link for background service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it looks like:

"iPhone OS doesn't allow you to add background processes."

via:

[How to implement Daemon process for background task in iphone sdk 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413154/how-to-implement-daemon-process-for-background-task-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

Just post a notification from selector, running in Background. Then, catch the notification and perform selector again.